# how to convert all tables from SDF file together to csv file in c# or any application which converts

Tags: c#, excel, sdf

```
using System;

using System.Collections.Generic;

using System.Text;

using System.Data.SqlServerCe;



namespace ExportSDF

{

class Program

{

static void Main(string[] args)

{

SqlCeConnection conn = null;

SqlCeCommand cmd = null;

SqlCeDataReader rdr = null;

try

{

conn = new SqlCeConnection(@"Data Source = C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server Compact Edition\v3.1\SDK\Samples\Northwind.sdf;max database size=256");

conn.Open();

cmd = new SqlCeCommand("SELECT * FROM Customers", conn);

rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

System.IO.TextWriter stm = new System.IO.StreamWriter(new System.IO.FileStream(@"C:\customers.csv", System.IO.FileMode.Create), Encoding.Default);

while (rdr.Read())

{

for (int i = 0; i < rdr.FieldCount-2; i++)

{

if (rdr[i] != null)

{

stm.Write(rdr[i].ToString());

stm.Write(";");

}

else

{

stm.Write(";");

}

}

if (rdr[rdr.FieldCount-1] != null)

{

stm.Write(rdr[0].ToString());

}

stm.Write(System.Environment.NewLine);

}


stm.Close();

rdr.Close();

cmd.Dispose();

}

finally

{

// Close the connection when no longer needed

//

conn.Close();

}

}

}

}
```

this program is not working please help me with a code or application which converts all the table together to csv file.i have some application which converts only one table at a time.i cannot select multiple table.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see, you got the code from [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/565cf11e-ee93-4016-a821-53703febc0b3/exporting-data-from-sdf-database-to-csv-file?forum=sqlce).
Could you please be clear on what does not work? What have you tried so far?
It seems to me that you only copied the code but didn't change the Data Source, which obviously won't work for you.

Thanks.

Comment: I modified the data source.problem is its not taking table header and column of type [LumId] VARBINARY(16) NOT NULL, is displayed like System.Byte[];